# Multiple images in a row on Gatsby / Markdown?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, gatsby, gatsby-image

Sorry if this question has already been asked, but is there a way to have two images side by side (or even a grid of images) in a page generated by Gatsby from a file Markdown ? I start the creation of my first site under Gatsby and for the moment, I only manage to display one image at a time, over the entire width (when i try to duplicate on side by side, They put themselves on top of each other.

Is there something to do on the css? Or the configuration takes place in gatsby-config.js ?

If anyone has a solution :)

**Thanks a lot !!**

Here's the two images in my .md file

```
![description](picture.jpg) ![description](picture.jpg)
```

Here's the part about markdown my gatsby-config.js

```
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-transformer-remark',
  options: {
    plugins: [
      'gatsby-remark-relative-images',
      {
        resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
        options: {
          maxWidth: 750,
          linkImagesToOriginal: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a clean solution, in Gatsby you can wrap your images with div containers.

code (in markdown)

```html
<div style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <div style = "width: 250px; 
  margin: 0 1rem;
    margin-bottom : 1.5rem;">
      <img style = "display: inline-block" src = "./6.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div style = "width: 250px; 
  margin: 0 1rem;
    margin-bottom : 1.5rem;">
      <img style = "display: inline-block" src = "./7.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

result will be :

[image]

I hope this helps you :)